# how to find all asked characters or combinations in string

Tags: python

I want insert some text and find in this text some selected characters with index in sequence for each letter, for example

all letters `L` and `O` in "hello world!"

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index for each characters use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) where the keys are the letters and  the values are lists containing the index/indexes where that letter appears, you can get the index of each character using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
s = "hello world!"

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)


for ind, ch in enumerate(s):
    d[ch].append(ind)
```

Then to find the index lookup using the letter:

```
In [46]: d["o"]
Out[46]: [4, 7]

In [47]: d["l"]
Out[47]: [2, 3, 9]
```

If you just wanted the index for a particular  letter you could use a list comp again using enumerate:

```
inds = [ind for ind, ch in enumerate(s) if ch == "o" ]
```

For you while logic you need to go from index + 1:

```
 string.find('o', index + 1)
```

If you don't you will simply keep finding the same letter at the same index and loop infinitely.

If you want to replace letters, create a mapping with a dict and use `dict.get` to do the replacing:

```
d = {"A": "E", "B": "X", "C": "M"}
s = "BACK"
print("".join([d.get(ch, ch) for ch in s]))
```

Comment: if I go this way how can I give +1 for the index to get next letter and break the loop after the end of the string ?

`string = "hello world"
index = string.find('o')
while index != -1:
    print (index)
    index = string.find('o', index)`

Comment: You are getting every index,   `[ind for ind, ch in enumerate(s) if ch == "o" ]` gets every index for o in the string. If you were using the while you would need to use  `string.find('o', index+1)` or you would loop forever.

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of editing the original

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything @Padraic Cunningham said (+1). To change the letters of certain letters, you could make a function that makes use of the **replace** method.

```
def modify(string):
    string = string.lower()  # changes all letters to lowercase
    string = string.replace("a","e")  # changes 'a' to 'e'
    string = string.replace("b","x")  # changes 'b' to 'x'
    string = string.replace("c","m")  # changes 'c' to 'm'
    return string


>>> text = "Beyonce is awesome!"
>>> print text
Beyonce is awesome!

>>> text = modify(text)
>>> print text
xeyonme is ewesome!
```